# Visual studio won't open safari for debugging

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, safari

I am trying to debug .netcore api's which I wrote. I was able to debug, but now Visual Studio does not open safari.

When I try to run the project and enter `https://localhost:5000/projectname`, it tells me that my computer is in offline mode, which isn't true.

I'm using a *MacBook P*ro and **VS for Mac**.

[VS screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7noUm.png)
[Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbsf9.png)

Comment: Your browser image published doesnt show the addressbar. Is there any error displayed from visual studio.

Comment: @XPD visual studio says build successful and the addresser says https://localhost:5001/myproject

Comment: In your question you have 5000 as the port for localhost, can you recheck with the port number your project is running?

Comment: @XPD my project is running on https://localhost:5000/projectname and the problem remains. I think it has something to do with the localhost but I don't know how to check and fix it.

Comment: You need to check whether a web server has started from vs or not.

Comment: the project is running but I can't access localhost in order to use the server.

Comment: Is your web server kestrel or iis?

Comment: I am using the net core Template for api's I don't know I am unfamiliar with net core I am just starting to learn about it

Comment: I posted 2 photos, one of the VS screen and one with the safari response to https://localhost:5001/weatherforecast (the name of the template )

Comment: Try removing ssl urls from your project and verify with just http. Properties->launchSettings.json

Comment: I deleted  "sslPort": 44331 and it didn't change a thing.

Comment: then try "http://localhost:5001/". Without https.

Comment: safari says the server is too busy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issues by deleting my https certificate and generating a new one
Using the following commands on the terminal:

To delete it:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
```

To generate a new one:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```