# Visual Studio For Mac debugger won't open a browser

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-mac

Following an update of Visual Studio for Mac to 8.10.7 (Build 17) Visual Studio's debugger no longer loads my project into a browser. After a successful build, the output stops with these lines:

> Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.9/System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. >Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> Loaded '/[folders containing solution, project]/bin/Debug/net5.0/[ProjectName].dll'. Symbols loaded.

I have tried refreshing the certificate as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59335767/visual-studio-wont-open-safari-for-debugging). I also tried debugging a completed project, opening it for the first time in this update. I got this dialog: [image] . After selecting Always Allow, the debugger loaded. I went back to the first application, that won't load and it still won't load.

It is in debug mode.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this one out? I am having the exact same issue!

Comment: @keithm, I never really did figure it out, although it hasn't done it lately. While it was still happening I tried alternating between Chrome and Firefox, which seemed to help a bit. And when switching browsers didn't help, I shut down VS for Mac and then reopened it. The debugger would work for a couple of times and that was sufficient for me, as I was usually trying to find one error message.

Comment: My experience sounds very similar to yours. What I end up doing is running without debugging and then attaching the debugger to the process. It seems to work but it’s pretty cumbersome! I also have the VS2022 preview and the same thing happens using it. If I figure it out I’ll let you know!

Comment: Please do! Thanks.